# Can one type of intent action fire two different services in different situations?

Tags: android, android-intent, nfc

I have written an Android app that reads NDEF message from tag and does something with it. This works well.
Now I want to write to tag, BUT only if I open app first, click "Write" button and move tag close. If app is not running (activity is not active) it should start another activity and read from tag as it already does.

So when I press "Write" button `NDEF_DISCOVERED` action should fire activity for writing to tag and when nothing is pressed (app not running) `NDEF_DISCOVERED` action should fire activity for reading from tag.

Is this possible and if yes, how? Thanks!

**EDIT:**
Maybe I don't need to fire new activities but instead just check values from previous state of activity and choose action based on that?

Comment: Why are you using services in the first place?

Comment: Because I don't need anything displayed on UI?  Or should I use activities anyway?

Comment: Well, `NDEF_DISCOVERED` only works with activities, AFAIK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to register for the foreground dispatch (`NfcAdapter.enableForegroundDispatch()`, see [Using the Foreground Dispatch System](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/advanced-nfc.html#foreground-dispatch)).

I'm not quite sure I understood your scenario: You want to press a write button, then your write activity is shown (maybe displaying a message that the user should tap the tag for writing), then the user taps the tag and then the data should be written.

If that is the case, you would register the foreground dispatch in the write activity's `onResume` method (and disable it again in the corresponding `onPause` method).

Answer (score -1):

you can register the `IntentFilter` dynamically in `onResume` and unregister it in `onPause`

see `registerReceiver()` and `unregisterReceiver()` at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html

Comment: Thanks! But when there are two intent filters with NDEF_DISCOVERED action, phone asks me to select which activity should it start..